# SQL Server : view with case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a view in SQL Server 2014 but when I execute the SQL statement, I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'MONTHNUMBER'

My statement:

```
CREATE VIEW [Metadata].[NEW_VIEW]
AS
    SELECT   
        dbo.fnFirstDayOfMonth(a.Year,a.Month) AS FR_OBS_DATE,
        b.Code AS COUNTRY,
        a.Groups AS COMMODITY,
        a.ImpValue AS OBS_VALUE,
        a.DexValue AS OBS_VALUE_2,
        a.RexValue AS OBS_VALUE_3,
        a.TexValue AS OBS_VALUE_4,
        0 AS UNIT_MULT,
        'NUM' AS UNIT_MEASURE,
        a.Month AS MONTHNUMBER,
        CASE a.Month
                WHEN 'January' THEN 1
                WHEN 'February' THEN 2
                WHEN 'March' THEN 3
                WHEN 'April' THEN 4
                WHEN 'May' THEN 5
                WHEN 'June' THEN 6
                WHEN 'July' THEN 7
                WHEN 'August' THEN 8
                WHEN 'September' THEN 9
                WHEN 'October' THEN 10
                WHEN 'November' THEN 11
                WHEN 'December' THEN 12
        END,
        CAST(a.Year AS varchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(MONTHNUMBER AS varchar(10)) AS TIME_PERIOD
    FROM 
        [Trade].[HS] a
    INNER JOIN 
        [Codelist].[Countries] b ON a.CountryName = b.Name
```

I would appreciate pointers on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You can't reference a column alias in another column within the same select statement. Also, you seem to have a scalar function in your query which is usually a performance sink hole. Last but not least you might want to take a peek here. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: Should it be CAST(a.Month as varchar(10))? MONTHNUMBER only exists as an alias for a.Month. This cannot be used in a CAST

Comment: use `CAST(a.month AS varchar(10)` instead of `CAST(MONTHNUMBER AS varchar(10)`

Comment: As a better solution I would suggest storing month and year in a single column with the datatype of date instead of storing them in different columns. It makes everything a lot more complicated to date information as strings.

Comment: I used `CAST(a.Year AS varchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(a.Month AS varchar(10)) AS TIME_PERIOD` instead, but I get another error: `Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 11.`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, `MONTHNUMBER` is an alias for `a.Month`, you can't use the alias there:

```
CREATE VIEW [Metadata].[NEW_VIEW]
AS
SELECT   --dbo.fnFirstDayOfMonth(a.Year,a.Month) AS FR_OBS_DATE, I think your problem is here
        b.Code AS COUNTRY,
        a.Groups AS COMMODITY,
        a.ImpValue AS OBS_VALUE,
        a.DexValue AS OBS_VALUE_2,
        a.RexValue AS OBS_VALUE_3,
        a.TexValue AS OBS_VALUE_4,
        0 AS UNIT_MULT,
        'NUM' AS UNIT_MEASURE,

        a.Month AS MONTHNUMBER,
            CASE a.Month
                WHEN 'January' THEN '1'
                WHEN 'February' THEN '2'
                WHEN 'March' THEN '3'
                WHEN 'April' THEN '4'
                WHEN 'May' THEN '5'
                WHEN 'June' THEN '6'
                WHEN 'July' THEN '7'
                WHEN 'August' THEN '8'
                WHEN 'September' THEN '9'
                WHEN 'October' THEN '10'
                WHEN 'November' THEN '11'
                WHEN 'December' THEN '12'
            END AS MonthName,

        CAST(a.Year AS varchar(10)) + '-' + 
              CASE a.Month
                WHEN 'January' THEN '1'
                WHEN 'February' THEN '2'
                WHEN 'March' THEN '3'
                WHEN 'April' THEN '4'
                WHEN 'May' THEN '5'
                WHEN 'June' THEN '6'
                WHEN 'July' THEN '7'
                WHEN 'August' THEN '8'
                WHEN 'September' THEN '9'
                WHEN 'October' THEN '10'
                WHEN 'November' THEN '11'
                WHEN 'December' THEN '12'
            END AS TIME_PERIOD

FROM [Trade].[HS] a
INNER JOIN [Codelist].[Countries] b
    ON a.CountryName = b.Name
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Sami. The view was created. When I query it, I get 
`Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'April' to data type int.`

Comment: I made your changes so that the numbers are 'text', but I get the same error - Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'April' to data type int.

Comment: What is the datatype of a.Month

Comment: The datatype of Month is nvarchar(255)

Comment: Same problem even with the removal of the CAST

Comment: @G.Welch Remove `dbo.fnFirstDayOfMonth(a.Year,a.Month) AS FR_OBS_DATE,` and see if it works

Comment: @ Sami Yes, removing the `dbo.fnFirstDayOfMonth(a.Year,a.Month) AS FR_OBS_DATE` fixed that problem. I seeing that **TIME_PERIOD** is in the format 2017-April and not what I was hoping for - 2017-04.

Comment: Oh, and **FR_OBS_DATE** must be in the view.

Comment: Note that I replaced `dbo.fnFirstDayOfMonth(a.Year,a.Month) AS FR_OBS_DATE,` with `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS FR_OBS_DATE,` and this seems to have solved the ` Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'April' to data type int` error. 

The **TIME_PERIOD** is still displaying 2017-April and not 2017-04 as expected.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

`MONTHNUMBER` isn't bound yet here

```
CAST(a.Year AS varchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(MONTHNUMBER AS varchar(10)) AS TIME_PERIOD
```

So I believe you will need to use `a.MONTH` in its place, such as

```
CAST(a.Year AS varchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(a.Month AS varchar(10)) AS TIME_PERIOD
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify this logic to:

```
SELECT . . .,
       month(cast(a.month + ' 2000' as date) as monthnumber,
       convert(varchar(7), cast(a.month + cast(year as varchar(255)) as date), 121) as time_period
FROM . . .
```

SQL Server has quite flexible date conversion capabilities.  They are very handy in this case.